# What are the signs of noisy labels in a dataset?

Tags: classification, supervised-learning, measurement-error

When learning a classification model in supervised machine learning, how can we test whether the labels in the dataset are noisy or not? Is there any particular way to check it or any specific sign to look for?

Comment: What about using anomaly/outlier detection techniques?

Comment: There is a Cook's distance defined for polytomous logistic regression : 
(https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/bmsp.12036)
 which can detect influencial datapoints, i.e. points which don't get along well with the model (so erronous labels for instance).
I guess another way would be to use a robust model and check points which are not well accounted for by it.

Comment: A noticeable number of datapoints in each class look like outliers. However, I am not sure whether they are outliers in the feature space or their corresponding labels are incorrect.